# MESSAGE_CONTENT_TYPE DIscord.js embed

Tags: node.js, discord.js

code:

```
module.exports = {
    minArgs: 2,
    expectedArgs: '<Channel mention> <JSON>',
    callback: ({ message, args }) => {
        const targetChannel = message.mentions.channels.first()
        if (!targetChannel) {
            message.reply('Specify a channel to sent the embed in')
            return
        }

        args.shift()

        try {
          const json = JSON.parse(args.join(' '))
          const { text = '' } = json

          targetChannel.send(text, {
            embed: json,
            })
        } catch (error) {
            message.reply('Invalid JSON')  
        }
    },
}
```

error:
RangeError [MESSAGE_CONTENT_TYPE]: Message content must be a non-empty string.
The bot should send an embed at the command !embed @tag JSON, but when I send json, I get an error. My json:
{ "title": "Embed", "description": "Test", "color": "0x00ff00" }

Comment: What's your question? `text` is an empty string and it says _"Message content must be a non-empty string"_.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are using V13 here is the way to send an embed

```js
send({ content: 'Text', embeds: [embed] });
```